# Why do I have to specify a default export twice in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The current setup of my project is as follows:

`src/components/Buttons.jsx`:

```js
const Buttons = () => {
    const DATA = [
        ...
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default Buttons;
```

`src/components/index.jsx`:

```js
export { default as Buttons } from './Buttons';
```

`src/index.jsx`:

```js
...
import { About, Buttons, Pictures, Icons } from "./components";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <div className="app">
            <Buttons />
        </div>
    </React.StrictMode>,
...
);
```

---

Whenever I change `src/components/index.jsx` to

```js
export * from './Buttons';
```

I get the error: `Attempted import error: 'Buttons' is not exported from './components'.`

- Why do I have to specify a default export in two separate places for the same component?
- Why can I not use `export * from './Buttons';` without getting the error?

Comment: Instead of `export default Buttons` do `export const Buttons = ...`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is by design.
`export *` and `import *` only import the named exports of a file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

if you wish to `export * from './Buttons'` then in Buttons.jsx you should `export const Buttons = () => {`.

if you never import like `import Buttons from './components/Buttons'` then you can drop the default export (`export default Buttons`) as you do not really need it.

Comment: The second snippet is using a named export.

Comment: the second snippet is the one that the OP is asking why when changed does not work.
export *, imports all named exports of the button and re-exports them from the index.

Comment: You're right. Perhaps you can add an example named export like `export const myFunc = () => {}` to your answer to show how it is supposed to work.

Comment: good idea. I added to the answer for completeness. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It comes from compatibility with `modules.exports`, aka, older versions of javascript. Your React can now transpile for IE6, if that is desired.

With modules.exports, a file would "usually" return an object with a key for any different value. This was the `default` and **singular** export.

`default` is an extra key towards that object, that you export like `export default varName` and import as `import defaultExportAndCanNameItAnythingIWantItToBe, {aNormalExportVariableName, andASecondairyOne} from './blah'`.

What you are trying to do is to "hack" that:

```
module.exports = {
   default: 'someValue',
   namedExportVariableName: 'probablySomeFunction'
}
```

`default` key, and rename it into a different key with the `as` statement.